# google chrome stuck when watching video at full screen size

Tags: google-chrome

when i watch video in google chrome at full screen mode its stuck and not more working, in normal size its work without any issues but at full screen size freeze chrome and desktop!
there is no problem with other browser like Mozilla Firefox and Epiphany
i well use ubuntu 18.04 with pantheon desktop (Elementary OS 5 Juno) and google chrome 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: same issue. Any idea someone?
Thanks

Comment: Facing the same issue. Please fix it ASAP or provide a workaround.

Comment: Do you have a link to the video?

Comment: its not related to specific web site :)

Comment: I was just curious since I noticed it too but couldn't remember where. Having an example might help someone reproduce the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an update that fixes this issue. Just update in AppCentre or run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: Did not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Here is the solution that I used.

**Step 1**: Copy the python code and make it into an executable file and place it on your home folder

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os,signal
import time
a=1
while (a==1):
    try:   
        #iterating through each instance of the proess 
        process=os.popen('ps aux | grep "brave.com/brave/brave --type=gpu-process" | 
        grep -v grep')
        str=(process.read())
        length=0
        length=len(str)
        if (length==0):
            print("Process Teminated..")
            a=2
        else:
            for line in os.popen('ps aux | grep "brave.com/brave/brave --type=gpu-process" | grep -v grep'):  
                fields = line.split() 
                #extracting Process ID from the output 
                pid = int(fields[1])  
                res=fields[3]
                res=float(res)/100*7.69*1024 #7.69 is the amount of ram i have.... yours might vary.
                # terminating process  
                if(res>100):
                    print(f"pid={pid} res={res}")
                    os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)  
                    print("Process Successfully terminated") 
                time.sleep(6)
                length=0
      
    except: 
        print("Error Encountered while running script") 
        time.sleep(10)
```

**Step 2**: Create a shell script to launch both the applications at the same time

```
cd /usr/bin/;brave-browser-stable & brave=$!
sleep 2
cd /home/<your-username-here>/;./kill-gpu-brave & kill=$! #I named my  python execulable file kill-gpu-brave
wait $brave
wait $kill
```

**Step 3**: Make this an executable file with `chmod +x <filename>` and launch brave through this file.

**Note:** For chrome the command will change. Please check your task manager. It will come under `--type=gpu-process`