# Instability in full screen videos ElementaryOs 5

Tags: release-juno, videos, elementary-project, xorg

has anyone personally faced instability in elementaryOS 5 with two screens in extended mode when opening videos in any browser in full screen mode? I open a video in full screen on one of the screens, whatever the video hangs, the browser stops responding, no matter what the browser, I also changed the computer but I kept both screen and the problem persists, I performed an installation clean and just installed the google chrome and mozilla browser.I found post on the stack with replies to use the upgrade and download the packages for fix, but my problem persists anyone got a solution?

[StackExASk Solution 1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/15561/google-chrome-stuck-when-watching-video-at-full-screen-size)
Not Worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check my answer here

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/16901/14940

Is only a bypass but still a way to see fullscreen videos while isn't fixed

Comment: Same, thanks.  One of the many bugs I've found in Juno so far after using it for less than an hour :-(

Comment: Still not fixed, any full screen video I have to use the hack of switching screen and switch back :-(